# ¿Cómo activar función por tecla en javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Quiero activar una función al pulsar una tecla, tengo este código pero no se porque no funciona, alguien sabe.

```
window.addEventListener("keydown", function change(event) {
let key = event.key

if (key == "ArrowRight") {
    document.getElementById('container').style.flexDirection = 'row';
} else if ("ArrowLeft") {
    document.getElementById('container').style.flexDirection = 'column';
}}
```

Comment: ¿Estas cargando el script con defer o estas haciendo un documet.ready? , proba alguna de esas opciones y comenta, proba tambien con letras simples en lugar de las flechas. El codigo parece estar bien, parece un problema de implementación.

Comment: Me da un error de sintaxis en la línea 9, pero no entiendo por que. He probado a poner unos console.log para ver si cargaba bien el script y los console.log los imprimia.

Comment: Podes poner mas código para poder verlo?

Comment: Eso es todo lo que tengo, el resto de código es html, solo tengo eso de javascript

Comment: Agregaste el defer en la cargar del JS?

Comment: Te falta el paréntesis de cierre para `.addEventListener()`, las dos llaves del final, una cierra el `if` y otra la función anónima.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ahí encontré el error, fijate que te estaba faltando cerrar el Parentesis al final de tu función

```js
window.addEventListener("keydown", (event) => {
  
  let key = event.key
    
  if (key == "ArrowRight") 
  {
   document.getElementById('container').style.flexDirection = 'row';
   document.getElementById('container').innerHTML = 'row';
   console.log("ArrowRight")
  } 
  
  else if (key == "ArrowLeft") 
  {
   document.getElementById('container').style.flexDirection = 'column';
   document.getElementById('container').innerHTML = 'column';
   console.log("ArrowLeft")
  }

})
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Prueba</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <script defer src="index.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="container">Contenedor</div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Mira, te hice una forma un poco mas resumida de hacer lo mismo, saludos.

```js
window.addEventListener("keydown", (event) => {
    let dir = {ArrowRight:'row',ArrowLeft:'column'}

    if (Object.keys(dir).includes(event.key)){
        document.getElementById('container').style.flexDirection = dir[event.key]
        document.getElementById('container').innerHTML = dir[event.key]
    }}
)
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Prueba</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <script defer src="index.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="container">Contenedor</div>
</body>

</html>
```